# ng-model overwritten within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-init

I have a table with an input field, I'm setting values to `ng-model` in each iteration of `ng-repeat`. I'm getting correct values in each iteration, but all of the `ng-model` values are overwritten by the last value of iteration. How can I solve this ?

view

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students_list">
        <td>{{student.Rollnumber}}</td>
        <td>{{student.Name}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="item in Allsubjects" >      
            <input   type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="da" 
                  ng-init="alert(student.Id)">
        </td>
</tr>
```

controller

```
$scope.alert = function(id)
{
    $scope.da =id;
};
```

This is What I'm getting (screenshot):
[image: This is What I'm getting (screenshot)]

331 is the result of last iteration. It is overwriting previous values.

Comment: it should have defferent model. like this `ng-model="item.da"`

Comment: @Hadi can you explain ? I'm a noob

Comment: please share `Allsubjects` object

Comment: @Hadi This table supposed to enter the marklist of students. All subject list of subjects fetched from database (sub1 sub2 sub3 in table header shown in screenshot).

Comment: Allsubjects does not seem to be connected to student_list; that seems to be the error; there is only one instance of student_list (appearing many times due to ng-repeat but all are referencing to the same object).

Comment: After fetching data in your callback function, do something like:

Comment: `for (studentProp in student_list) {var student = student_list[studentProp]; student.Allsubjects = Allsubjects}`

Comment: Then in your template, write `student.Allsubjects` rather than Allsubjects only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is expected behaviour that last value of the iteration will be assigned to "da"

You can resolve this by

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students_list">
        <td>{{student.Rollnumber}}</td>
        <td>{{student.Name}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="item in Allsubjects" >      
            <input   type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="student['da']" 
                  ng-init="alert(student)">
        </td>
</tr>
```

and the alert function

```
$scope.alert = function(student)
{
    student["da"] = student.id;
};
```

Here, we are just creating a new property named "da"(took name you used) for every object of student in student_list array, so it will have value respective to it's object.

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of your problem is your object definition.

try to  create your objects like this

```
$scope.student_list = [
  student1 = {
    Rollnumber : 9999,
    Name : "Foo", 
    sub1 : 0 
  }
]
```

etc... It should give you a different `ng-model` for each element. but If you can share your object it would be more helpful to find the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students_list">
        <td>{{student.Rollnumber}}</td>
        <td>{{student.Name}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="item in Allsubjects" >      
            <input   type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="da"+item 
                  ng-init="alert(student.Id,)">
        </td>
</tr>
```

Here we add dynamic value to the model (i.e item), now it will not override the model values, and you can easily get it by your defined function:

```
$scope.alert = function(id,item)
{
    $scope.da+item = id;
};
```